# Java 3D array initialization

Tags: java, arrays, 3d

I need to represent some spatial points: x,y,z

when I try to initialize the array like this:

```
int[][][] points
{
   {
      {100, 120, 10},
      {100, 120, 18},
      ...
   }
}
```

I got an error: Uncompilable source code - not a statement

where is the error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just forgot the `=` sign and a semicolon `;`

```
int[][][] points = {{{100, 120, 10}, {100, 120, 18}}};
```

Comment: and the semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 3):

```
int[][][] points = {{{100,200,300},{120,200},{200,250}}};
```